# Regarding Test Class Method

Tags: unit-test

Please provide an example of when `Test.isRunningTest()` becomes `true` and `Test.isRunningTest()` becomes `false`? I am not able to understand this concept.

I have tried using `Test.isRunningTest` in an Apex class and it returns `false`, but the same method called from a test returns `true`.

Comment: Have you checked this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_isRunningTest  I think it's quite clear. If it's not enough, let us know and we may try to explain in other words.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_isRunningTest) explains:

> Use this method if you need to run different code depending on whether
>   it was being called from a test.

It is very rarely needed (and best avoided if at all possible) and when it is needed you add it to the production code not the test code.

One place I have consistently used it is to stop an error happening in tests where a field name is added to the standard controller:

```
public AccountDeepCloneController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
    this.sc = sc;
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
        sc.addFields(new String[] {'Name'});
    }
}
```

because otherwise `addFields` generates an error in tests.

Another place is when programmatically generating PDF data as again the normal call generates an error in tests:

```
Blob pdf = !Test.isRunningTest() ? pr.getContentAsPdf() : Blob.valueOf('Test content');
```

Another place is to put `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` objects into a `@TestVisible` list instead of passing them to `Messaging.sendEmail` as email sends are awkward to test.

Comment: please explain with the small code to show the difference

Comment: @Elavarasan There is not much more I can do here. When the product code is launched fro ma test Test.isRunningTest() returns true and when the product code is launched normally Test.isRunningTest()  returns false. I've posted typical examples of the use of this in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Test.isRunningTest() Returns true if the currently executing code was called by code contained in a test method, false otherwise. Use this method if you need to run different code depending on whether it was being called from a test.

for example

you cant send http request in test method so you have to provide result by this check

```
public class AuthCallout {


   public void basicAuthCallout(){
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
     req.setEndpoint('http://www.yahoo.com');
     req.setMethod('GET');

     String username = 'myname';
     String password = 'mypwd';
   string result;
     Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
     String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
     EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
     req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {

     Http http = new Http();
     HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
     result = res.getBody());

}
else
{
     result = '{"widget":{"debug":"on","window":{"title":"Sample widget","name":"main_window","width":500,"height":500}}}';

}

   }
}
```

here we check if code is not executed by test class it will make an http call and get result else we will provide demo result for further use
checkout this link, it will explain you how Test.isRunningTest() is used,

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_isRunningTest

Comment: Before the HttpCalloutMock mechanism was introduced this was the right choice, but a cleaner mechanism now for this situation is [Testing HTTP Callouts by Implementing the HttpCalloutMock Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm).

Comment: but if we need the response for further looping and record creation, i think this simple if else statement would be good enough as we can put the fake resonse over there no need to create an extra class for that and also cover our code coverage and its just an example i showed to use Test.isRunningTest

Comment: Just making the point that (usually) HttpCalloutMock is the better way to go.